# on my subdomain mkdir() function creates the Directory in the main root instead of the wanted directory, and it does not uploade the image into it

Tags: php, file-upload, subdomain

I have this function which is working perfectly on the localhost:

```
$avatar       = $_FILES ['avatar'];
$avatarName   = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
$avatarSize   = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
$avatarTmp    = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
$avatarType   = $_FILES['avatar']['type'];
$avatar       = strval($avatarName);

if(!file_exists("data\\uploads\\users\\$email")){
  mkdir("data\\uploads\\users\\$email", 0777, true);
}
   
move_uploaded_file($avatarTmp, "data\\uploads\\users\\$email\\".$avatar);
```

on Localhost:
this code creates the wanted directory in the wanted path and moves the avatar file inside it.

on the Subdomain:
-it creates a Directory in the main root and names it (data\uploads\users\example@mail.com)
-and it creates in the main root another file "which is the $avatar" and names it (data\uploads\users\example@mail.com\example.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem was using the doubled backslash (\) the correction is to use a single normal slash (/) in all the lines